# Parse CSV file of strings into a 2d array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, csv

I have a CSV of strings that looks like so:

```
"","Orange","","","","","","Red",""
"Orange","","Blue","","","","","Black",""
"","Blue","","Pink","","Any","","","Any"
"","","Pink","","Green","Red","","",""
"","","","Green","","Blue","","",""
"","","Any","","BLue","","Orange","",""
"","","","Red","","Orange","","Green","Black"
"Red","Black","","","","","Green","","Yellow"
"","","Any","","","","Black","Yellow",""
```

and I would like to place it into a 2d array of strings (I'll ignore the quotation marks later).  I've tried many different ideas but can't seem to get any to work properly.

This code is close but the output is off in a way I can't make sense of.  It also parses and tokenizes the file correctly.  It seems to go bad when it puts the tokens into the array.  Here is the code taken from my program:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 #define VERTICES 9

 int main(void)
 {
     const char *colors[VERTICES][VERTICES];

     char buffer[1024];
     char *record, *line;
     int i = 0;
     int j = 0;
     FILE *fstream = fopen("Colors.dat", "r");
     if (fstream == NULL)
     {
         printf("\n file opening failed\n");
         return -1;
     }
     while ((line = fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fstream)) != NULL)
     {
         record = strtok(line, ",");
         while(record != NULL)
         {
             printf(" %s", record);
             colors[i][j] = record;
             //printf(" %s"), colors[i][j];
             record = strtok(NULL, ",");
             j++;
         }
         j = 0;
         ++i;
     }

     printf("\n============================================\n\n");

     for (i = 0; i < VERTICES; i++)
     {
             for (j = 0; j < VERTICES; j++)
             {
                 printf("%s | ", colors[i][j]);
             }
         printf("\n");
     }
     return 0;
 }
```

If you uncomment the line in the second nested while loop and comment out the two for loops you get odd output as well.  Thanks!

Comment: Maybe something like `colors[i][j] = record;` --> `colors[i][j] = strdup(record);`?  `colors`, as now used, is just fill with pointers into `buffer`.

Comment: @chux Wow, that might have done it.  Do you want to put that up in an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP is simple recording the address of the read buffer, which gets updated on subsequent reads.

Need to allocate/copy the strings for later use.

```
// colors[i][j] = record;
colors[i][j] = strdup(record);
```

The remaining `colors[i][j]` in a line should be set to `NULL`.

```
     while(j < VERTICES && record != NULL) {
         printf(" %s", record);
         colors[i][j] = strdup(record);
         assert(colors[i][j]);
         record = strtok(NULL, ",");
         j++;
     }
     while(j < VERTICES) {
         colors[i][j] = NULL;
         j++;
     }
```

Robust code would also check for allocation failures (`assert(colors[i][j])` and would free the memroy when done.